# Access log replay for load testing? Jmeter Pitfalls and Competitors

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

**Context**

We wish to use "replay" web server access logs to generate load tests. JMeter had come to mind as I'd recently read blog posts about using jmeter in the cloud (e.g. firing up a number of Amazon EC2 instances to generate the load)

For years I had heard of JMeter's ability to replay access logs, but in reviewing this feature I found the following.

**[Access Log Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler)**

- DOES:

  - recreate sessions, i.e. handle the `jsessionId` token (thought it tries to approximate sessions by IP address);
- DOES NOT:

  - handle POST data (even if you could configure apache/tomcat to write out post data to the access log, jmeter access log sampler only handles 'common' log format).

Post data would go a long way toward recreating actual load.

Additionally, the documentation describes the Access Log Sampler as "alpha code" even though it's 8 years old. It doesn't seem actively maintained. (That's longer than Gmail's beta.)

**HttpPerf**

Another blog post pointed me to the httpperf tool. I've started to read up on it:

- blog: http://www.igvita.com/2008/09/30/load-testing-with-log-replay/
- httpperf: http://code.google.com/p/httperf/

**Summary**

- What's the best way to generate load testing 'scripts' from real user data?
- What has worked best for you?
- Pros and cons of various tools?

Comment: +1 for the question.  I haven't been able to get JMeter to do this.

Comment: A question, what is the your configuration to dump post data in access log. I could not find easy way to do this?

Comment: Faced with the same problem. I tryed to play logs from apache server, but noticied that i need to configure logging post body and cookie. Can you share your apache configuration?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter + HTTP Raw Request + Raw Data Source for me works well

Comment: +1 
@andrey-pokhilko can you add more details to your answer? 
From where did you get HTTP Raw Request - i can't configure apache to log post requests data.

What does it mean 'Raw Data Source' ?

Comment: Raw Data Source is a plugin for JMeter. But these days I'd not recommend using it, there are other approaches possible, like BlazeMeter Taurus tool.
And yes, there is no easy way to get POST request bodies with Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I will describe how do we solve this problem using our own LT tool called [Yandex Tank](https://github.com/yandex-load/yandex-tank)
It can handle simple access.log but only 'GET' requests, too. When there's a need to make other types of requests, we use other ammo formats (ammo is a file containing all the requests that we gonna send to our server). Example:

```
342
POST / HTTP/1.1^M
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
Keep-Alive: 300^M
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AGHTUNG^M
Content-Length: 1400^M
Connection: Close^M
^M
--AGHTUNG^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fp"; filename="fp_tank"^M
Content-Type: application/octet-stream^M
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary^M
...
--AGHTUNG--^M
```

A number ('342') on the first line is the size of a following request. Request is in it's raw format. You could write a simple script in your favourite language that generates such ammo files from your access.log and then use it for load testing.

Such ammo format makes it really flexible. For example, [this](https://gist.github.com/direvius/9207582) code generates ammo from FCGI logs (POST bodies are encoded in Base64). But on the other hand you will need to handle sessions manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily replay access logs **with POST** data using [ZebraTester](http://www.zebratester.com/). It has many plugins similar to JMeter and also ability to add inline scripts using which you can easily target POST payload, URLs, timestamps, etc. from the access logs. You can run load tests directly from the tool locally or copy the recorded script to the [SaaS portal](https://www.apicasystem.com/online-web-load-testing/) to run massive million virtual user load tests